# Node.js sequelize ConnectionManager.getConnection was called after the connection manager was closed

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, multer, pm2

We are using sequelize as ORM in express app. I am getting this error on production environment while failing to reproduce this on local setup. On production, the site is hosted using pm2 and there are 4 workers running for the application. I tried running the same codebase using pm2 on local, but couldn't reproduce this issue.

I am facing this issue in only one of my APIs which processes CSV and saves the record in the database. The error is caused while trying to execute some query while serving the response for the upload API.

The util function when run using another API works fine.

The error traceback

```
Error here===> Error: ConnectionManager.getConnection was called after the connection manager was closed!
at ConnectionManager.getConnection (/home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:113:13)
at /home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:613:111
at /home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:70:21
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at retryAsPromised (/home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:60:10)
at Sequelize.query (/home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:606:12)
at PostgresQueryInterface.select (/home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:952:33)
at Function.findAll (/home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1753:47)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
at async Function.findOne (/home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1917:12)
at async sendInviteToUser (/home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/src/services/linkService.js:43:22)
at async uploadUser (/home/ubuntu/unberry-backend/source/src/controllers/linkController.js:67:33)
```

Using multer for file processing. Please share the insights! Thanks in advance.